# Android: Click on "HTML" link programatically

Tags: java, html, webview, hyperlink

Here is the website code (plz note that I don't own the website and I can't change website code. Also the website is being called inside a webview) -

```
<div style="display: block;" id="dl_link"><a href="/get?video_id=j5-yKhDd64s&amp;h=-1&amp;r=-1.1" style="display:none"><b>Download</b></a><a href="/get?ab=128&amp;video_id=j5-yKhDd64s&amp;h=dcea2722f5cc36d82d09f865e0cb08d7&amp;r=1408169981816.1424164396"><b>Download</b></a><a href="/get?video_id=j5-yKhDd64s&amp;h=-1&amp;r=-1.1" style="display:none"><b>Download</b></a></div>
```

Please not that the code is not repeated. I have copied it as it is.

How to programmatically click on that link through java? The link changes everytime we post a new url (webpage [link](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?ab=128&video_id=j5-yKhDd64s&h=ed2efb29bca278b049e805913ef7c035&r=1408167985917.1424557616)).

Comment: document.getElementById('dl_link').click() in javascript

Comment: I tried web.loadUrl("document.getElementById('dl_link').click()"); but didn't work. I want to load that javascript on already loaded page.